# Calling function after thread/function completion

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, cocoa-touch, ios

I would like to remove a view from another after the completion of a thread/another function in the class.  At the moment I am using the following code to remove it after a set time period, but obviously, the function completion times varies

```
LoadingView *loadingView =
    [LoadingView loadingViewInView:self.view];

    [loadingView
     performSelector:@selector(removeView)
     withObject:nil
     afterDelay:10.0];
```

Is there a simple way of doing this?  I've looked online and can't seem to find anything.  Does this mean I have to write this functionality myself?

Comment: Why can't you just call [loadingView removeView] when you want to remove it? Of course, keeping in mind UIKit thread safety and all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove a view from the other thread with:

```
[loadingView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(removeView) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

Of course you just need to maintain a reference to the loadingView somewhere that the thread can access.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that works great.  Slight problem, though its not major, theres a slight (but noticeable) delay between the loading view disappearing and the data being displayed.  What I'm loading are images from URLs in the thread, any idea how to prevent that?

Comment: Good call, TheBlack. Updated to reflect this case.

Comment: Hmm, theres still a delay.  Would it be to do with the fact that I'm downloading the images from URLs?

Comment: @Jack: at what point are you dismissing the loading view? If you dismiss it before the image is fully loaded, you will obviously have a delay.